# What is the rationale for division by 8 during ADPCM audio compression?

Tags: audio, compression, dpcm

I am studying ADPCM and while I understand the concept I cannot find an explanation for some of the calculations in available implementations such as the one outlined [here](https://wiki.multimedia.cx/index.php/IMA_ADPCM):

```
step_index = step_index + ima_index_table[(unsigned)nibble]

diff = ((signed)nibble + 0.5) * step / 4

predictor = predictor + diff

step = ima_step_table[step_index]
```

The + 0.5 also appears odd but I believe it is to avoid truncation loss as an expanded version of above diff calculation shows:
`diff = ((step * nibble) + (step / 2)) / 4`

Adding half the stepsize seems sensible for reducing truncation error from quantisation but as the goal is to convert from 16 to 4 bit audio I cannot understand why the step value is divided by 4.

Any insight appreciated

Answer (score 1):

An ADPCM encoder is a nonlinear negative-feedback closed-loop control system. The nonlinearity is the quantizer, and the negative feedback is the subtraction of the predictor signal from the input signal. Like all feedback loops, if the loop gain (product of forward path and feedback path gains) is too high, instability (or oscillation) results. The factor 4 is to ensure stability by maintaining "low enough" loop gain.

In a linear-feedback closed-loop control system, prediction of stability is much easier, and concepts like necessary phase margin and gain margin are well-established in the literature.

A non-linear system (like ADPCM) is much more complicated, since the small signal gain of the non-linearity (the quantizer) can vary from 0 to infinity, depending on the quantizer input signal magnitude and shape. This makes loop stability much harder to predict analytically. The factor 4 is not required to be exact, and there is a range of factors that will still result in loop stability. Higher factors will result in lower overall quantization noise. However, with high enough factors the loop becomes marginally unstable, and overall quantization noise will increase again, until a threshold is reached where quantization noise takes a giant increase due to loop instability. This factor is signal-dependent, and good design dictates choosing a somewhat conservative factor so that "oddball" signals don't excite instability.